# Rest API: Response HTTP status code for applicative semantic error

Tags: api, rest, http

Suppose to have a REST API which updates the stock of some products in an e-commerce portal:

**URL**    : /products/stock
**METHOD** : PUT 
**BODY**   :

```
{
 "PRD001": 3,
 "PRD002": 2
}
```

Where the request body is a map made of **<<PRODUCT_CODE>> : <<USER_REQUIRED_QUANTITY>>** entries

At some point, the server receives a well-formed syntactic request, but the logic behind the API fails because:

- One or more of the sent PRODUCT CODES do not exist.
- The USER_REQUIRED_QUANTITY requested for one of the products having PRODUCT_CODE is unavailable because of insufficient stock.

Which HTTP CODE should the REST API return for these "semantic applicative errors"?

In my opinion:

- It shouldn't return 400 - BAD REQUEST because the REQUEST is well-formed from a syntactic perspective.
- In the case of an inexistent product, it shouldn't return 404 -NOT FOUND because the resource is related to a stock and not to a specific product. Returning 404 - NOT FOUND could lead the client intto an error.
- It could return a 409 - CONFLICT (The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the resource)
- It could return a 422 Unprocessable Entity (The server understands the content type and syntax of the request entity, but still server is unable to process the request for some reason). Anyway, this status code is part of WebDAV specific and not part of the HTTP)

What do you think about this specific use case?
And, in a more general way, in which way do you handle HTTP Status codes according to applicative semantic errors?

Thank you

Comment: /products/stock seems like the resource is a stock and it should be updated, i.e. stock levels of products are managed via this "stock" resource. What seems to be the real resource in this scenario is /products/order. It's a question of whether the client does the work, i.e. uses /products/id to get the stock level of each product and /products/order according to available stock or the server does the work, returning an error as it is an error, ordering non-extistent stock. The combination of product+stock could be 404 as it literally may not exist. The server could return a header with stock

Comment: We are assuming that the work is done on the server side. Thinking about it, the main problem could stay in the wrong endpoint URL. The "stock" is a product's property and the "/products/stock URL" doesn't have much sense. It should be simply "PUT /products".  In this way, the first scenario (one of the products doesn't exist) could be implementing returning a 404 - NOT FOUND. But what about the second scenario, in which the requested stock is greater than the available stock?

Comment: A stock property of 5 when the available stock is 0 would be an out of range condition. The question is, does a product with no stock exist? It can't be ordered as there are no instances of it left, 404. It's then time to consider the business process behind the resource, which is really an Order that contains one or more Product instances. If the business process allowed for it, any no-stock Product in the Order could be added to a DeferredOrder. Or the PUT could return the out of stock Products it couldn't Order.

Comment: another question is, why doesn't the client know how much stock is left for each of the Product it wants to Order?

Comment: The client knows, at a given moment, how much stock is left for a product. But let's imagine that a second client has submitted an order (decreasing the available stock for some products) between the moment in which the first client has retrieved the product (with the stock data) and the moment in which it confirms the order. The original product's stock retrieved by the first client is not yet valid and so the server should block it.

Comment: Indeed. Sounds like "428 Precondition Required" - "This response is intended to prevent the 'lost update' problem, where a client GETs a resource's state, modifies it and PUTs it back to the server, when meanwhile a third party has modified the state on the server, leading to a conflict." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#client_error_responses

Comment: @codebrane that's not what "precondition required" is for. It's important to read the definition and don't take the 'error string' for face value. If there's no `If-*` headers, 428 doesn't apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Important idea - status codes are metadata of the [transfer of documents over a a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) domain; they describe the semantics of the HTTP response so that general purpose HTTP components can do intelligent things (e.g. invalidate cached responses).

---

> Which HTTP CODE should the REST API return for these "semantic applicative errors"?

The fact that the values in the request body are the problem strongly suggests that we want some flavor of 4xx Client Error semantics.

I'm inclined to guess that the simplest approach would be to use [403 Forbidden](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-403-forbidden)

```
The 403 (Forbidden) status code indicates that 
the server understood the request but refuses 
to fulfill it.
```

Any nuance that you need to share with the user/bespoke client is described in the body of the 403 response.

---

From what I can tell, [409 Conflict](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-409-conflict) isn't *right*, but also isn't going to get you into a lot of trouble.

For a general purpose component, 403 and 409 are handled essentially the same way -- in theory a general purpose component could try to "resolve the conflict" on its own and resubmit the request, but in practice we don't have a standard for describing the nature of the conflict, which means that the component isn't going to know a way to modify the request.

So while I would decline a pull request (PR) that used a 409 here, I would also *accept* a PR that used a 409 and also included a decision record documenting the trade offs that the implementer had considered in this specific context (for example - it might be important that your human operators easily be able to distinguish this case from authentication issues when scanning access logs).

In other words, make the boring choice unless you have really good reasons to do something else.  If you have really good reasons to do something else, *write them down*.

---

## 422

> My doubt about this one is that it is not part to the HTTP specs.

Don't be worried at that.  HTTP status codes are intended to be [extensible](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-status-code-extensibility).  Anything you find in the [IANA status code registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) should be considered safe to use.

Also, today, the registered reference for 422 is the current HTTP Semantics specification ([RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-422-unprocessable-content)).

That said, I wouldn't use it here, because I don't think the semantics are as good a fit for your circumstance as 403.

```
The 422 (Unprocessable Content) status code indicates that the
server understands the content type of the request content 
(hence a 415 (Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate),
and the syntax of the request content is correct, but it was unable
to process the contained instructions. For example, this status 
code can be sent if an XML request content contains well-formed 
(i.e., syntactically correct), but semantically erroneous XML
instructions.
```

My interpretation of this is that we're trying to indicate that there's a problem specific to the semantics of the request body (ex: a required field is missing).  It announces that we're unable to process the request, rather than announcing that the processing failed.

In other words, 422 is "I don't know what this means", where 403 is "I know what this means, but I won't do it."

> We also have considered using the 403 - FORBIDDEN code, but it seems to be more related to authorization issues.

The specification gives wider latitude than the most common usage.

```
a request might be forbidden for reasons unrelated 
to the credentials.
```

That said, choosing a different status code can be the right engineering trade off.  If the benefits of doing the right thing are small, and the costs (in particular, the support and operational costs) are large, well... maybe being successful is more important than being right.

Comment: Just to add that, regardless of the returned HTTP Status, the API implements the https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807 and always returns specific information about the error. Anyway, in order to adhere as much as possible to the REST specification, we would also choose the right HTTP status code. We also have considered using the 403 - FORBIDDEN code, but it seems to be more related to authorization issues. What about "422 - Unprocessable Entity" ? My doubt about this one is that it is not part to the HTTP specs.

Comment: I added more observations about 422; let me know if that helps?

Comment: Actually, the 403 - Forbidden, with a response which details the occurred error, might be the right HTTP code.  And what about the URL format and HTTP Method ? Take in mind that, from a Domain perspective, the "stock" is a Product's property.  On second thought, considering that the API doesn't update the entire "Product" document, it might be better to use the "PATCH" method (for partial updates) instead of the PUT one (for complete updates). I'm also in trouble with the "URL": PATCH - /products/stock or PATCH - /products?  I wouldn't expose an API for generic partial updates on a Product